# Removing leading/trailing slashes in .BAT file ruins everything

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out why my .bat file randomly closes... but I've narrowed it down to this:

```
IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0,-1%
IF %var:~0,1%==\ SET var=%var:~1%
```

Ideally what I'm eventually trying to accomplish is to remove any leading or trailing slashes or backslashes from `%var%`, which is set by user input.

The above lines work, but not when inside an `IF` statement when `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is set AND when the variable is also set inside the `IF` statement.

For example, the following works if I remove the above lines, but crashes otherwise:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set somevar=blah
if !somevar!==blah (
    set /p var="-> "
    IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0,-1%
    IF %var:~0,1%==\ SET var=%var:~1%
    echo !var!
)
pause
```

If I remove the `IF` condition, however, it does work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p var="-> "
IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0,-1%
IF %var:~0,1%==\ SET var=%var:~1%
echo !var!
pause
```

And if I keep the `IF` statement but move the `set /p var="-> "` outside of it, then it also works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set somevar=blah
set /p var="-> "
if !somevar!==blah (
    IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0,-1%
    IF %var:~0,1%==\ SET var=%var:~1%
    echo !var!
)
pause
```

I know that when Delayed Expansion is enabled that I have to use `!` instead of `%` for variables, but I've tried every combination of that on those lines to no avail, and I don't understand how they work enough to troubleshoot further.

And if there's a more efficient way to accomplish what I've described, by all means please mention it. I'm somewhat new to batch-writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've implied, the key to your problem is the use of `delayed expansion`.

When `delayedexpansion` has been invoked,

`%var%` refers to the value of `var` as it was when any `code block` (parenthesised sequence of instructions) was *encountered* (actually, `var` is simply replaced by *its value at that time* and then the instructions are executed)

`!var!` refers to the *run-time* value of `var` - that is, the value at the current time, having possibly been altered by the operation of the `code block`.

so, examining from your code

```
set /p var="-> "
IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0,-1%
IF %var:~0,1%==\ SET var=%var:~1%
echo !var!
```

This is *executed* as

```
set /p var="-> "
IF ==\ SET var=
IF ==\ SET var=
echo !var!
```

because the value of `var` at the start of the code is *nothing*, consequently  it "crashes" because the `if` statement syntax is incorrect.

To fix the problem, use

```
set /p var="-> "
IF !var:~-1!==\ SET var=!var:~0,-1!
IF !var:~0,1!==\ SET var=!var:~1!
echo !var!
```

where each reference to `var` becomes the value *as changed by the "set /p"* or subsequent `set` operations.

However, `set/p` does *not* clear the variable if you simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It leaves the variable *unchanged* (but its value happens to be *nothing* at the time)

Hence, a better approach is

```
set /p var="-> "
IF "!var:~-1!"=="\" SET "var=!var:~0,-1!"
IF "!var:~0,1!"=="\" SET "var=!var:~1!"
echo !var!
```

where the quotes around the `if` arguments ensure that the arguments are not *empty* and those around the `set` arguments ensure that the variable does not acquire any stray trailing spaces that may exist on the instruction line.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I had tried replacing all the `%` with `!` but I hadn't tried adding quotes. Works great.